# Safe user added HTML in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, xss

I need to store and display content with user-generated markup, like questions at stackowerflow, for example.
What proper ways for it do you know? Pseudo-tags? Real HTML-filtration?
What WYSIWYG editors can deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use redcloth or similar with Markitup http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/, that does Html, Textile, Wiki Syntax, Markdown, BBcode